# VS Code Custom Snippets parameters hints

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am creating my own snippets for my script, and would like to make hints in the parameters.

```
"GDX Round": {
        "prefix": "gdxround",
        "body".
          "GDX.Round(${1:int}, ${2:round_decimal})"
        ],
        "description": "GDX Round"
    },
```

Something like this:

[image: parameter hints]